# Opacity on elements with background image such as input field in IE7-IE8

Tags: css, cross-browser

I can't seem to get this working, although it should be possible in theory, I'm trying this for over a week now, but it's just doesn't work in IE7 or IE8, works as intended in FF, Chrome, Safari...

Code on fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/xqQ7r/4/

HTML :

```
<div style="margin: 50px 0px 0px 250px;">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="test button" />
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/mxCABKj.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 31px;
    min-width: 100px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* text shadow */
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #4f4f4f;
    /* borders */
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #4f4f4f;
    opacity: .75;
    /* Standards Compliant Browsers */
    filter: alpha(opacity=75);
    /* IE 7 and Earlier */
    /* Next 2 lines IE8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75);
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    /* IE 7 and Earlier */
    /* Next 2 lines IE8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Thanks for all thoughts and solutions in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, it is working.

i fiddled a modified version of your code here http://jsfiddle.net/xqQ7r/8/

I just modified opacity of the button to 0.25 and background-color to red **so you can see** the effect.

```
.button {
    background-color:red;
    opacity: 0.275;
}
```

Here is cross-browser .css for opacity

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: That does not help me in any way. I need to figure how to make it work with image...

Comment: I dont know how else to tell you it is working. See this other fiddle where i made the background-color to transparent : http://jsfiddle.net/xqQ7r/9/   OH, let me guess, Press F5 in jsFiddle to make sure your image is loaded in the example.

Comment: Are you sure you see black button on your end, changing opacity on hover in IE? I surely don't see that :S

Comment: OK, just to mention, jsFiddle has a bug with the background-image. It is not loaded properly. What i have to do is to load the image http://i.imgur.com/mxCABKj.png in another tab, then hit F5 on jsFiddle in order to see the gray linear texture.

Answer (score -1):

You can always use jQuery.

```
  $('.button').css('opacity', 0.275);
```

Comment: Not an answer.  OP did not say anything about using jQuery.  Besides, if it doesn't work in CSS, it's not going to work with jQuery... it's just easier for the  programmer.